# Are there Christmas markets in Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland, seasonal

I've been in Germany on christmas and almost every city has a Chrismas Market. Are there Christmas markets in Switzerland? Which are the most famous/interestings? When do they end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This page](http://www.linker.ch/eigenlink/weihnachtsmarkt.htm) list all the big Christmas markets in Switzerland. I can really recommend those two that are in the [main stations of Lucerne and Zurich.](http://www.christkindlimarkt.ch/) It sounds weird but they are really nice. As a plus next to the Christmas market in Zurich's main station, there are a lot of open air bars in the courtyard of the [Landesmuseum](http://www.musee-suisse.ch/d/zuerich/index.php) where you can get Glühwein and Raclette, typical food and drink during Christmas in Switzerland. As lejohn already mentioned, also the [Christmas market in the Niederdörfli](http://www.gld.ch/maerkte-im-niederdorf/6?task=view) is worth a visit.

Here you see a picture of the Christmas market in Zurich's main station. The huge Christmas tree is decorated with [Swarovski](http://www.swarovski.com) crystals.

[image]

And here is a picture of the Landesmuseum's courtyard where you can get Raclette and Glühwein. It is also possible to do some ice skating there:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of Christmas markets in Switzerland, just [pick one next to the place you are staying](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en/service-updates/events.html?strubrik=2161).

A nice market is the one in the [old town of Zürich](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en/service-updates/events/event-2799551.html). It is located along [Hirschenplatz, Niederdorfstrasse and Rosenhof](http://maps.google.de/maps?q=Hirschenplatz,%20z%C3%BCrich&hl=de&ie=UTF8&ll=47.373971,8.544627&spn=0.005144,0.010246&hnear=Hirschenplatz,%20Rathaus,%208001%20Z%C3%BCrich,%20Schweiz&t=m&z=17&vpsrc=6). In 2011, it takes place from the 8th to the 23rd of December. Its opening hours are from Monday to Friday 11am - 8pm and on Saturday and Sunday from 11am to 6pm.

Comment: Note that that list has a 'more results' link at the bottom, otherwise you miss out on some (notably Montreux, which is the only one I've ever visited: I must admit that even though people come from far and wide, I'm not *sure* it's worth travelling more than an hour for).

Answer (score 3):

As I remember, in Geneva at least, there are open air markets on a weekly basis. (At least in the late 1990s, when I was there.) They do not "end," therefore, and there would be something for Christmas.

Comment: But a German Christmas market is not simply a market open around Christmas time!

Comment: @Annoyed: Geneva is in the FRENCH, not German-speaking part of Switzerland.

Comment: Sure, but once again the question is about German Christmas markets, not about regular markets open for Christmas.

Answer (score 3):

Another place in Swiss French part is [Montreux](http://www.montreuxnoel.ch/), it is probably the biggest and longest running Christmas market in the French-speaking region.

Near Geneva, there is one in Carouge (the town is next to Geneva).

Apparently the biggest Christmas market in Switzerland is the one of [Basel](http://www.basel.com/en/christmas-basel-home-switzerlands-largest-christmas-market)

[This site](http://www.marches-noel.org/category/marches-de-noel-en-suisse/) is resuming all markets in Switzerland (and other countries).